# Why does Express.js defaults views location in proess.cwd() instead of __dirname?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I noticed that quite a few tutorials I've walked through on Express.js are setting the views by:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

And that's because in Express.js docs, it states:

```
views The view directory path, defaulting to "process.cwd() + '/views'"
```

I am wondering since it is more predictable and safe to use __dirname, why did Express.js team decided to default it to process.cwd() at the first place?

Comment: Variable `__dirname` is local to module, so there it's hard to get it outside of the module. On the other side `process.cwd()` is sane default.